# How to block a particular portion of page during ajax load?

Tags: jquery

I have 5/6 divs on a page.

During a click operation, I need to get some data from server and refresh div2 and div3

But I want to prevent the user from doing anything on these 2 divs until it is done.

Some small plugin will be helpful. I am using colorbox plugin on that page for other things.

Thx

Comment: You'd do it with code of some sort, but I don't see any here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the jQuery plugin [BlockUI](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/)
It's really easy to setup and allows you to block and element on a page, or the entire page, and it's very customisable. There's loads of demo's available on the site as well to get you started :)